# Insert statements with different datatypes inside transaction using Laravel with SQL Server fails

Tags: sql, sql-server, laravel, transactions, sql-insert

A database table named `lines` with only has 1 column `price`

#### Model

```
class Line extends \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model
{
    protected $table = 'lines';
    protected $guarded = ['id'];
}
```

#### Table

```
+-------------+-----------+-------------------+-------------------------+---------------+
| COLUMN_NAME | DATA_TYPE | NUMERIC_PRECISION | NUMERIC_PRECISION_RADIX | NUMERIC_SCALE |
+-------------+-----------+-------------------+-------------------------+---------------+
| price       | numeric   |                19 |                      10 |             3 |
+-------------+-----------+-------------------+-------------------------+---------------+
```

When I run this code I get an error

#### Code

```
DB::transaction(function() {
  Line::insert([
    ['price' => 13.52],
    ['price' => 35]
  ]);
});
```

#### Error

> SQLSTATE[22018]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '13.52' to data type int. (SQL: insert into [lines] ([price]) values (13.52), (35))

I have done some research

- If I remove the transaction it works fine
- If I change the value `35` to `35.00` it works fine
- If I insert them one-by-one it also works fine
- The statement `insert into [lines] ([price]) values (13.52), (35)` runs fine inside multiple SQL clients (DBeaver, SQL Operations Studio) also if executed inside a transaction (`BEGIN TRANSACTION; .... COMMIT;`)

**Setup**

- PHP 7.1
- Debian 9 (but problem also occurs on Windows)
- SQL Server 2012
- Laravel: 5.8

**My question**

Is there some way I can handle this issue globally without having to resort to any of the previously mentioned fixes?

Since it works fine in an SQL editor, I assume it must be either a Laravel issue, or a PHP SQL driver issue?

Comment: The error message seems to be saying that your ORM model for `price` is text, not numeric, and also the `price` column appears to be `int`, not decimal.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I have added the code of my model to the question. The field is a `numeric(19,3)` - I have no idea why the insert statement wants to convert it to an integer

Comment: can you provide sql output

`show create table lines`

Comment: @mikrafizik I'm afraid `show create table lines` is a MySQL command, and doesn't work in SQL server, but I've updated the question with information from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`

Answer (score 0):

The issue here seems to be that your Laravel model is not properly defining the `lines` field to map to a decimal column.  One option would be to use `casts` property of your model ([documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#attribute-casting)):

```
protected $casts = [
    'lines' => 'real',
];
```

Regarding the error on the SQL Server side, I don't know why it is trying to convert the text to integer, but in any case, if it can't make an implicit conversion it would throw an error similar to this.

Comment: I tried adding the casts to the model, but same error. I also tried some of the other types (float, double, decimal:<19,3>, decimal:3) defined in the docs for Attribute Casting https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting but still the same error :(